# Reading page size from MapDocument object?

Tags: arcpy, export, jpg

I have a set of 30 MXD's with different page size. I would like to export maps with their name file which include the mxd's page size. i have this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxd)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "Layers")[0]      
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc,r"C:\Project\out\\"+ os.path.basename(mapdoc.filePath).replace ('.mxd','') +".jpg")      
    print 'ExportToJPEG'
    mapdoc.save()
    del mxd
```

the row that start with "arcpy.mapping " is Connected with the next row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
import arcpy, os
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:\\Project"

for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join("C:\\Project", str(mxd)))
    mapdoc_name = str(os.path.splitext(mxd)[0])
    width, height = str(round(mapdoc.pageSize.width, 2)), str(round(mapdoc.pageSize.height, 2))
    output = os.path.join("C:\\Project\\out", mapdoc_name + "_" + width + "-" + height + ".jpg")
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, output)
    del mapdoc
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Help for MapDocument (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000n000000) has a code sample that illustrates how to read the page size from a MapDocument object into two variables (`pageWidth` & `pageHeight`):

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
print mxd.pageSize
print mxd.pageSize.width; print mxd.pageSize.height
pageWidth, pageHeight = mxd.pageSize
print pageWidth, pageHeight
```

Comment: I want to see the page size in the exported JPG
, for example environment a3 or  environment 29.7-20